# JSON issue in Java

Tags: java, json, api

I have a simple JSON output that looks like

```
"api":{"results":1,"predictions":[{"match_winner":"1","under_over":null,"goals_home":"-3.5","goals_away":"-1.5","advice":"Winner : Paris Saint Germain","winning_percent":{"home":"50%","draws":"50%","away":"0%"},"teams":{"home":{"team_id":85,"team_name":"Paris Saint Germain","last_5_matches":{"forme":"75%","att":"71%","def":"86%","goals":10,"goals_avg":2.5,"goals_against":2,"goals_against_avg":0.5},"all_last_matches":{"matchs":{"matchsPlayed":{"home":2,"away":2,"total":4},"wins":{"home":2,"away":1,"total":3},"draws":{"home":0,"away":0,"total":0},"loses":{"home":0,"away":1,"total":1}},"goals":{"goalsFor":{"home":7,"away":3,"total":10},"goalsAgainst":{"home":0,"away":2,"total":2}},"goalsAvg":{"goalsFor":{"home":"3.5","away":"1.5","total":"2.5"},"goalsAgainst":{"home":"0.0","away":"1.0","total":"0.5"}}},"last_h2h":{"played":{"home":4,"away":3,"total":7},"wins":{"home":3,"away":1,"total":4},"draws":{"home":1,"away":1,"total":2},"loses":{"home":0,"away":1,"total":1}}},"away":{"team_id":95,"team_name":"Strasbourg","last_5_matches":{"forme":"25%","att":"21%","def":"64%","goals":3,"goals_avg":0.75,"goals_against":5,"goals_against_avg":1.25},"all_last_matches":{"matchs":{"matchsPlayed":{"home":3,"away":1,"total":4},"wins":{"home":0,"away":0,"total":0},"draws":{"home":2,"away":1,"total":3},"loses":{"home":1,"away":0,"total":1}},"goals":{"goalsFor":{"home":3,"away":0,"total":3},"goalsAgainst":{"home":5,"away":0,"total":5}},"goalsAvg":{"goalsFor":{"home":"1.0","away":"0.0","total":"0.8"},"goalsAgainst":{"home":"1.7","away":"0.0","total":"1.3"}}},"last_h2h":{"played":{"home":3,"away":4,"total":7},"wins":{"home":1,"away":0,"total":1},"draws":{"home":1,"away":1,"total":2},"loses":{"home":1,"away":3,"total":4}}}},"h2h":[{"fixture_id":35755,"league_id":22,"league":{"name":"Ligue 1","country":"France","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/leagues\/61.png","flag":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/flags\/fr.svg"},"event_date":"2017-12-02T16:00:00+00:00","event_timestamp":1512230400,"firstHalfStart":1512230400,"secondHalfStart":1512234000,"round":"Regular Season - 16","status":"Match Finished","statusShort":"FT","elapsed":90,"venue":"Stade de la Meinau","referee":"Ruddy Buquet, France","homeTeam":{"team_id":95,"team_name":"Strasbourg","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/95.png"},"awayTeam":{"team_id":85,"team_name":"Paris Saint Germain","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/85.png"},"goalsHomeTeam":2,"goalsAwayTeam":1,"score":{"halftime":"1-1","fulltime":"2-1","extratime":null,"penalty":null}},{"fixture_id":121334,"league_id":434,"league":{"name":"Coupe de la Ligue","country":"France","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/leagues\/65.png","flag":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/flags\/fr.svg"},"event_date":"2017-12-13T20:05:00+00:00","event_timestamp":1513195500,"firstHalfStart":1513195500,"secondHalfStart":1513199100,"round":"8th Finals","status":"Match Finished","statusShort":"FT","elapsed":90,"venue":"Stade de la Meinau (Strasbourg)","referee":null,"homeTeam":{"team_id":95,"team_name":"Strasbourg","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/95.png"},"awayTeam":{"team_id":85,"team_name":"Paris Saint Germain","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/85.png"},"goalsHomeTeam":2,"goalsAwayTeam":4,"score":{"halftime":"1-2","fulltime":"2-4","extratime":null,"penalty":null}},{"fixture_id":35656,"league_id":22,"league":{"name":"Ligue 1","country":"France","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/leagues\/61.png","flag":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/flags\/fr.svg"},"event_date":"2018-02-17T16:00:00+00:00","event_timestamp":1518883200,"firstHalfStart":1518883200,"secondHalfStart":1518886800,"round":"Regular Season - 26","status":"Match Finished","statusShort":"FT","elapsed":90,"venue":"Parc des Princes","referee":"Thomas Leonard, France","homeTeam":{"team_id":85,"team_name":"Paris Saint Germain","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/85.png"},"awayTeam":{"team_id":95,"team_name":"Strasbourg","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/95.png"},"goalsHomeTeam":5,"goalsAwayTeam":2,"score":{"halftime":"3-1","fulltime":"5-2","extratime":null,"penalty":null}},{"fixture_id":37712,"league_id":4,"league":{"name":"Ligue 1","country":"France","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/leagues\/61.png","flag":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/flags\/fr.svg"},"event_date":"2018-12-05T20:00:00+00:00","event_timestamp":1544040000,"firstHalfStart":1544040000,"secondHalfStart":1544043600,"round":"Regular Season - 16","status":"Match Finished","statusShort":"FT","elapsed":90,"venue":"Stade de la Meinau","referee":"Antony Gautier, France","homeTeam":{"team_id":95,"team_name":"Strasbourg","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/95.png"},"awayTeam":{"team_id":85,"team_name":"Paris Saint Germain","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/85.png"},"goalsHomeTeam":1,"goalsAwayTeam":1,"score":{"halftime":"1-0","fulltime":"1-1","extratime":null,"penalty":null}},{"fixture_id":121449,"league_id":436,"league":{"name":"Coupe de France","country":"France","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/leagues\/66.png","flag":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/flags\/fr.svg"},"event_date":"2019-01-23T20:05:00+00:00","event_timestamp":1548273900,"firstHalfStart":1548273900,"secondHalfStart":1548277500,"round":"16th Finals","status":"Match Finished","statusShort":"FT","elapsed":90,"venue":"Parc des Princes","referee":"Johan Hamel, France","homeTeam":{"team_id":85,"team_name":"Paris Saint Germain","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/85.png"},"awayTeam":{"team_id":95,"team_name":"Strasbourg","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/95.png"},"goalsHomeTeam":2,"goalsAwayTeam":0,"score":{"halftime":"1-0","fulltime":"2-0","extratime":null,"penalty":null}},{"fixture_id":37860,"league_id":4,"league":{"name":"Ligue 1","country":"France","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/leagues\/61.png","flag":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/flags\/fr.svg"},"event_date":"2019-04-07T19:00:00+00:00","event_timestamp":1554663600,"firstHalfStart":1554663600,"secondHalfStart":1554667200,"round":"Regular Season - 31","status":"Match Finished","statusShort":"FT","elapsed":90,"venue":"Parc des Princes","referee":"Thomas Leonard, France","homeTeam":{"team_id":85,"team_name":"Paris Saint Germain","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/85.png"},"awayTeam":{"team_id":95,"team_name":"Strasbourg","logo":"https:\/\/media.api-sports.io\/football\/teams\/95.png"},"goalsHomeTeam":2,"goalsAwayTeam":2,"score":{"halftime":"1-2","fulltime":"2-2","extratime":null,"penalty":null}}],"comparison":{"forme":{"home":"75%","away":"25%"},"att":{"home":"77%","away":"23%"},"def":{"home":"71%","away":"29%"},"fish_law":{"home":"0%","away":"0%"},"h2h":{"home":"85%","away":"15%"},"goals_h2h":{"home":"67%","away":"33%"}}}]}}
```

The code I have written to read the `teams` array is as follows:

```
    String json = response.body().string();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    String api = obj.getString("api");
    JSONObject object2 = new JSONObject(api);
    String first = object2.getString("teams");

    System.out.println(first);
```

The error I am getting is that `JSONObject["api"] not a string.` Can someone please let me know how to read this. I am new to Java.

Comment: The string you have posted is not valid JSON.

Comment: And even if it where valid JSON, the value of `"api"` is an object, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, `api` relates to another object: `{"results":1, ...`. Use `getJsonObject` instead. See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html).

Answer (score 0):

Going by `JSONObject` I am assuming you are using [org.json](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html)

In any case, `"api"` is a json key which does not map to a String, but instead maps to a nested json or `JSONObject` in language of the library.

You need to do, `obj.getJSONObject("api")` instead. Same for `teams`.

You would use the `getString`, `getBoolean`, `getInt` on leaf fields like `team_name`, `team_id` etc.

You can refer to the [docs](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/index.html) for more examples and complete documentation.

Comment: obj.getJSONObject("api")  is giving me the JSON after API... how do I get the value of results? I tried         JSONObject api = obj.getJSONObject("api");
        
        String results = api.getString("results"); ... but its saying even results is not a string

Comment: You need to do it on the inner JSONObject. Also "results" is an integer. `obj.getJSONObject("api").getInt("results");`

Answer (score 0):

Your json text is invalid, so

```java
final String text = "{" + json;
```

, and

```java
final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(text);
final String api = obj.getString("api");
final JSONObject object2 = new JSONObject(api);
final String first = object2.getJSONArray("predictions").getJSONObject(0).getString("teams");

System.out.println(first);
```